# JSCH: closing channel and session

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I'm doing some SFTP operation with JSCH:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = null;
ChannelSftp sftpChannel = null;
try {
    session = jsch.getSession(user, host, Integer.valueOf(port));
    session.setConfig(JSCH_OPTIONS);
    session.setPassword(password);
    session.connect();
    Channel channel = session.openChannel(SFTP_CHANNEL_ID);
    channel.connect();
    sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;

    // some sftp operations

} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Error while SFTP session", e);
} finally {
    sftpChannel.exit();
    session.disconnect();
}
```

My question is: when I'm done is it enough to call disconnect() on the session object, or the exit() on channel is a must before?
Thanks!

Update: I checked the behavior and there are no errors, but I'm not quite sure the sockets/etc are cleaned up correctly.

Comment: 'netstat' would tell you that.